# Excel Cell Context Menu - Macro

Tags: excel, menu, cell

I added a macro to the Excel Cell Context Menu.

This is the main code,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim NewControl As CommandBarControl
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
   Set NewControl = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add
    With NewControl
      .Caption = "Inserir Data"
      .OnAction = "Module1.OpenCalendario"
      .BeginGroup = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Here you can see the result,

[image: Excel Cell Context Menu]

Ih there anyway to put this macro on the top of the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Set NewControl = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(before:=1)
```

Comment: Did Not work that way but i've tried Add.(,,,1) and it finally works. 
Thanks for the help.